# How do I change CockroachDB's default database?

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

When I connect to CockroachDB using `cockroach sql`, I have to prefix all table names with the name of the database:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table1;
```

If I forget to specify the database, like

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

I get the error `pq: table "table1" does not exist`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the database from an active SQL session by running:

```
SET DATABASE = [database]
```

You can also specify this when you connect by passing the `--database` argument to `cockroach sql`:

```sh
cockroach sql --database=[database]
```

Both of these are set per-session, so you’ll need to use them every time you connect.

If using a connection string, you can specify the database as the path segment of the URL, e.g.:

```
postgresql://root@localhost:26257/[database]
```